# ios changing tags itunesconnect when the app is already upload

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect

I have an app already in the app store but I want to change the tags on the app but I can not find a way of doing it. Any of you knows how can this be done or I need to submit a new version with the tags I want?. I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: You must submit an update to change the tags (among other meta data).

Answer (score 2):

You need to submit a new version. They can't be changed once the app is approved.